# Can I use different line length between f90 and for in one project?

Tags: fortran, line, limit, gfortran

I am trying to combine two Fortran projects using gFortran. But one project is written using f90 with free form and another one using .for with fixed 132 line length form. Can I set up the different line length according to Fortran file type in one project as below?

-ffixed-line-length-132  for .for
-ffree-line-length-none  for .f90

Thank you

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Please do not completely rewrite your question when it has already been answered. Instead please literally start a new question post and ask a new question - for example how tonadjust the CMake configuration. You can take the [tour] to see how to use the site.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know how to use this site. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. I was not sure so I just went ahead and tried it.

```
 gfortran -ffixed-line-length-1000 -ffree-line-length-1000 longline.for longline.f90
```

compiled two files with very long lines without any problem.

The same happened for `132` for the former and `none` for the latter, but it correctly complained when I exceeded 132 for the fixed form file.

Anyway, be aware that you can always compile your files in separate steps and use different flags in each of these steps:

```
     gfortran -ffixed-line-length-132 longline.for -o longline-fixed.o
     gfortran -ffree-line-length-1000  longline-fixed.o longline.f90
```

For large projects it is typical to use some build system that organizes the compilation into these steps automatically (make, CMake, SConstruct, FoBiS.py,...).

Comment: Thank you. It worked!